# Sequential directories creation in Python

Tags: python, naming, directory, sequential, convention

I'm trying to find how to create sequential directories with specific padding. For a given number it should create directories:

```
def createDirectories(number=10, name='seq'):
    for i in range(1, number+1):
        os.mkdir(name+i)
```

But it should produce directories in following naming convention

```
seq0010
seq0020
seq0030
...
seq0100
```

How to format numbers in that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this expression to obtain the directory name `seq0010` from the input `1`:

```
dirName = 'seq%03d0' % 1
```

Replace `1` with `i` and you're set.

Comment: +1 for being the only one to notice the question asked for multiples of 10.

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> myNum = '5'
>>> print myNum.zfill(3)
>>> '005'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use string formatting to create the entire folder name at once:

```
>>> 'seq{0:03d}0'.format(3)
'seq0030'
```